# How to edit a ng-template to use my HTML?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, web-component, ng-bootstrap

I am building a webcomponent based on the [accordion component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) from ng-bootstrap. You can try the original component on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/gglganeblrd). What I would like is that

```
<ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
</ng-template>
```

generate

```
<div role="tab" id="ngb-panel-1-header" class="card-header ">
    <a href="" aria-expanded="false" aria-disabled="false" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" role="button" style="padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;">
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
}--><!---->
     </a>
 </div>
```

instead of

```
<div role="tab" id="ngb-panel-1-header" class="card-header ">
    <a href="" aria-expanded="false" aria-disabled="false">
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet": "[object Object]"
}--><!---->
     </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution you could use is the power of FOSS! What is the power of FOSS? Well ng-bootstrap is a [MIT Open Source project](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE). What you can do is look for the [Accordion module](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/) and fork it! I dont think it is the easiest way to achieve what you want but at least it will work. Lets see.

1. Search the Accordion module inside ng-bootstrap.
2. Create an empty module in your project. I called it `accordion-next`.
3. Create an empty component in your project. I called it `accordion-toto`.
4. Copy/paste the ng-bootstrap module in yours and fix any errors you face. `isString` for example.
5. Use your module.
6. Enjoy.

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwhzog)

Comment: I mark this as solved because it solve my problem. I would love to here another solution though.