# How can I colorize an element with css through the shadow dom?

Tags: css, angular, sass, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a component called *accordion-next*. This component can be see as a template. I have a component called *accordion-toto*. This second component is using *accordion-next*. it is a kind of a filler for the template.

if *accordion-next* was an interpolated string it would be:

```
`<a href>${content}</a>`
```

and *accordion-toto* would be:

```
content = "<div><div><span class="caret">▼</span></div></div>"
```

so *accordion-toto* will print

```
<a href><div><div><span class="caret">▼</span></div></div></a>
```

ok. Now, I want to add some scss to *accordion-toto*. This scss is

```
a:hover .caret,
{
    color: red;
}
```

Of course it doesnt work. I try to use `:host`, `:host-context`, `:host(:hover)`, `:host-context(:hover)` then `/deep/` and a mixed of all of this. What case did I missed?

You can see the following Stackblitz for a complete example:

[Stackblitz complete demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwhzog-7z8pzp)

Relate to: [How to edit a ng-template to use my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50741268/1248177)

Edit: I use to have rotate issue. Thank you @Shadowlauch for pointing it. My problem is still here with a 'basic' attribute.

Comment: This seems to be CSS issue. You are using a transform on an inline-element (span), that does not work. Have a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwhzog-7tczr9?file=app/accordion-toto.scss

Comment: @Shadowlauch indeed. This is a part of the problem. Thank you for pointing out. I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the incorrect combinators. Try using the code below. You also need to set the display property to inline-block so that the rotation does work (it does not work on inline elements, as pointed by Shadowlauch's comment)

```
:host  ::ng-deep [aria-expanded="true"] .caret,
{
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }

:host ::ng-deep [aria-expanded="false"] .caret
{
  display: inline-block;
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwhzog-r3ckel?file=app/accordion-toto.scss)

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you! I explore a bit more and I check this.

Comment: is there a way without `::ng-deep `, `/deep/` or `::shadow`? They are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "display: block" for the span element in order to rotate, because span is an inline-element